# How to create a reactive stream that processes every time an event fires

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

How to kick off a reactive pipeline from an event and have it run each time the event fires...

The value inside the event is not relevant...

So far I have:

```
    PublishSubject<Object> linkAll = PublishSubject.create();

    linkAll.flatMap(x -> getObservableThatFetchesData())
            .doOnNext(data -> actOnTheData(data)).subscribe();
```

And then when the event fires I do:

```
linkAll.onNext("start");
```

Now this works great... but only once. The event only works once.

I want the pipeline to "run" each time the event fires...

Comment: Each time you call `onNext`, the pipeline would run.

Comment: Seems like problem in `getObservableThatFetchesData()`. Did you tried simplify example, so It can be runned?

Comment: I think zella is right here. Might `getObservableThatFetchesData` be completing somehow the stream?

Comment: Thanks all for your input... looks like you are right. For some reason it started working.

The wrinkle in this question is that this code is actually compiled to javascript via gwt so it's using gwt's rxjava implementation (which may have caused the anomaly)

Comment: Since you ignore errors, the most likely cause is `getObservableThatFetchesData()` failing silently. On desktop, the global error handler would have printed a stacktrace so the GWT version may have printed something on the console.